# What does "German layout support" do?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

In the Keymap configuration section, there's a checkbox labeled: **German layout support**. What does it actually do?

[image: Keymap configuration]

The documentation simply states:

> This check box appears when a non-English keyboard layout has been detected. When you type any character in the editor, the keyboard layout is recognized and a notification appears.

But that doesn't explain what the effect of the feature is. I experimented with both states of the checkbox, but I couldn't figure out any differences whatsoever.

Comment: Could it be that it changes the shortcuts so that the movement on the keyboard stay the same? (German keyboards typically use QWERTZ)

Comment: @T0xicCode I have no idea. Finding out what it does is further complicated by this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143147

Comment: I believe this option is attempt to deal with this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63779

Comment: @OliverSalzburg did you find out what it does?

Comment: @fxlae Nope. It is still a complete mystery :D

Answer (score 1):

This option enables support for certain hotkeys with "de", "fr", "it" and "uk" layouts. Without it some combinations will not work (like AltGr+7 to type "[" with German keyboard).

Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142462.

Comment: It works just fine for me without the option enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I just foolishly activated this checkbox without knowing what it does, and it seems to reinterpret my keyboard as English layout (y becomes z, shift+8 is a '*' instead of '(' etc). Sounds banal so far, but what this egregiously also does is **remove the checkbox** because clearly your keyboard is English now - i.e. I cannot deactivate this feature from inside the program.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html?search=caret here they have the path to the address for the relevant config file (keyboard.xml) that I had to manually reset, just in case anyone else ever runs into this problem.